# Regex for filename with quotes in multipart

Tags: regex, filenames, multipart

I'm trying to parse a multipart/form-data request properly, it works unless the file that is beeing uploaded contains double quotes.

The request looks like (excerpt from wireshark):

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="b'e\"e.JPG"
```

So the file is actually called b'e"e.jpg on my local filesystem. The browser escapes the quotes properly.

I want to grab the filename `b'e\"e.JPG` out of this string.

I found a regex for grabbing quoted strings with escaped quotes inside:

```
/"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"/i
```

(source http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/stringescapedmulti.html)

The regex works perfectly when applied on the string `"b'e\"e.JPG"` but when I try to scope it only on the `filename=` part, like:

```
/filename="[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"/i
```

I won't get any results.

Any help would be really appreciated

**Edit**:

I'm working with JavaScript, so I put the regex on js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hDBcs/

Thanks!

Simon

Comment: Just a quick test with RegexBuddy works fine for me, is there another part of the Regex that might be messing it up?

Comment: Hi, thanks for testing :) but in javascript it doesn't work unfortunately. I've added a quick test on jsFiddle (see edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly the problem is that you are not using brackets in order to get needed parts:

```
/filename="([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"/i
```